# React Redux deeply nested objects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, redux

Say I have a fairly simple nested, fetched object.

It contains many pieces of information and the schema is fixed.

Some items are nested such:

```
obj:{
  one:{
    x: "A",
    y: "B",
    more:{
      z: [1, 2],
      0: "C",
      extra: {
        a1: "b1",
        a2: "b2"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That's as deep as it goes.

Redux stores this information fine.

Why cant I retrieve **one.more.0** or **one.more.extra.a1** in react?

I can get **one.x**.

I can set state with **one.more**, then retrieve **.0**, but not **.extra.a1**.

I understand there are supposed to be reasons for this, but where this simple use-case exists, I find it troubling that it requires hoops to use information which is both accessible and available otherwise.

Any suggestions to get around this which don't involve normalising/redesigning the data to fit the package?

Ideal world: **this.props.aReducer.one.more.extra.a1**

Many thanks

EDIT*
Is this possible, or must such nested values be knit together pre-render:

```
render(){
  return(
    <div>
      {this.props.aReducer.one.more.extra.a1}<br />
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: What does the documentation say?

Comment: Sorry, not entirely sure what you mean. React-wise ,from what i read, react wont handle deeply nested objects.

Comment: You mean it says it just doesn't, and no reason is given?

Comment: Redux _should_ be able to handle nested state as long as you code your reducers and state-mappers appropriately. What data is your component getting? Is the data stored correctly in the Redux store?

Comment: I can verify redux is fine with it. The component receives everything appropriately, but when it comes to rendering (i should have specified) i get undefined errors on any prop or state below a couple of levels. A.b works but A.C.b = "cannot find b of undefined" though i can setState x:A.C and x.b is true. I've had this many times and always resign to flattening the data to use it in render.

Comment: Check that your initial state includes all those undefined properties.

Comment: I've updated my question as I wasn't very clear. Thanks for bearing with me.

Comment: @PedroCastilho You were of course correct. I was ignorant that the same was true of redux stores default state as of component state. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue isn't with the deeply nested object, but more likely with the defaults of your state or lack of validation. In order to render `one.more.extra.a1` each part of the path must exist, ie `one` must be an object with `more` as an object with `extra` as an object (`extra` doesn't have to have an `a1` property to render properly as it would just return undefined instead of throwing an error). Trying to get a property on undefined will always throw an error. This typically means the state wasn't properly initialized or you aren't checking to make sure each part of the path exists.

One way to check each part of the path:

```
var a1 = 'Some default value';
if (one && one.more && one.more.extra) {
  a1 = one.more.extra.a1;
}
```

Another option is to use something like lodash's `_.get` [link](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#get) which does this check for you.

Comment: Yes so if I define the whole structure in initial state it should not throw an error, but I was using state as an example. I want to just render props from redux which apart from this scenario works. State shouldn't have any bearing, or am I mistaken?

Comment: I am mistaken. I wrote the store so long ago I forgot that it also has its own default state aside from component state. That was rather silly of me. Thank you for your help.